# Accessing session in Sinatra Middleware

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack, warden

I am working on a Sinatra Project and have set some variables in the session for later usage.

The scenario for which I need help for is that I want to access the session object in a middleware class. I am using warden for authentication.

I want to do something similar below in the Middleware class:

```ruby
class MyMiddleware
    def initialize(app, options={})
        @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
        puts "#{session.inspect}" 
    end
end
```

Is there a possibility for doing that?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

You can't use Sinatra's `session` method in Rack middleware, but you can access the session directly through the `env` hash.

Make sure the session middleware is before your middleware (so in Sinatra `enable :sessions` should be before `use MyMiddleware`), then the session is available through the key `'rack.session'`:

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app, options={})
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    puts env['rack.session'].inspect
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

You might prefer to use a [`Rack::Request`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Request.html) object to make it easier to access the session and other parts of the `env` hash:

```
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  puts request.session.inspect
  # other uses of request without needing to know what keys of env you need
  @app.call(env)
end
```

Comment: Thanks matt. Will give it a shot and let you know the results. Cheers.

Comment: Any idea what it means if `env['rack.session']` is `{}` but I can see the cookie in `env['HTTP_COOKIE']`?

Comment: see my response below on why rack.session is {}

Answer (score 0):

For me, matt's answer worked, but I had to make sure that my `use` statements in sinatra were in the right order.  The cookie declaration has to come before my middleware:

```
class ApiDocs < Sinatra::Base

use Rack::Session::Cookie, ... #etc
use MyMiddleware # my middleware that uses session
```