# Is there a way to get session cookie name in rack middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, rack, rack-middleware

I use middleware class in Rack, Ruby on Rails and Sinatra applications.

**Rack application**

config.ru:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, key: '_dummy_session', secret: '...'
use MyMiddleware
run Dummy.new
```

**Ruby on Rails application**

config/initializers/secret_token.rb:

```
Dummy::Application.config.secret_key_base = '...'
```

config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
Dummy::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_dummy_session'
```

config/initializers/my_middleware.rb:

```
Dummy::Application.config.middleware.use 'MyMiddleware'
```

**Middleware class**

lib/my_middleware.rb:

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    ...
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

How can I get the name of session cookie ('_dummy_session') in `MyMiddleware#call` method?

Comment: The name? Do you mean the string used for the key, `'_dummy_session'`?

Comment: Yes, '_dummy_session'.

Comment: If you look at `env` after `@app.call(env)` is called you'll see the session inside it. Take a look in the env for `"HTTP_COOKIE"`, `"rack.request.cookie_hash"`, and inside of that last one `"rack.request.cookie_string"`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113162/accessing-session-in-sinatra-middleware